# Second order implicit derivative

Tags: calculus

The equation
$\begin{equation}
x^3 \ln x + y^3 \ln y = 2z^3 \ln z
\end{equation}$
defines $z$ as a differentiable function of $x$ and $y$ in a neighbourhood of the point $(x,y,z) = (e, e ,e)$. Calculate $z_1 (e,e)$ and $z_{11}(e, e)$.

**Attempt at solution**

Define $F(x,y,z) = x^3 \ln x + y^3 \ln y - 2z^3 \ln z = 0$. Then according to the implicit function theorem

$\begin{align}
z_1 &= -\frac{F_1}{F_3} \\
&= \frac{3x^2 \ln x + x^2}{6z^2 \ln z + 2z^2}
\end{align}$

so $z_1(e,e) = \frac{1}{2}$. I have solved $z_{11}$ but to be honest, using the quotent rule was a pain so I was wondering if there exists a more efficient way. Brute forcing my way through the problem I noticed that
$\begin{align}
z_{11} &= -\frac{F_{11}}{F_3} \cdot z_{1}
\end{align}$ but I'm at a loss how I could obtain that result without all the ... rigmarole. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought: avoid the quotient rule by multiplying out your $z_1$ to get
$$6z_1z^2\ln z +2z_1 z^2 = 3x^2 \ln x +x^2.$$
Now do the derivatives wrt $x$ of each term, where you apply the chain rule, at two points the desired $z_{11}$ appears, and at some other points you get a $(z_1)^2$.

Of course that's still a bit messy since one has to plug in the previous $z_1$ result into the places where $(z_1)^2$ appears...

I once tried to write a general formula for the second derivative in the two variable case, but it got so unwieldy that I thought it better to do concrete problems by the above method. [The formula had so many mixed partials and second pure partials to put in it, that it looked like more trouble than it was worth to try to apply the formula rather than do the particular problem directly.]